# Cakephp Routing not working in IIS server

Tags: php, cakephp, iis, iis-7, routes

I have hosted my Cakephp application on IIS server. It is hosted here - [http://pradanya.iihmr.edu.in/](http://pradanya.iihmr.edu.in/staff/senior_research_officers)

Css and javascript working fine but routing for all pages shown only home page. Like when page - http://pradanya.iihmr.edu.in/staff/senior_research_officers showing home page but its actual page not shown.

My web.config file code -

```
    <configuration>
   <system.webServer>
     <rewrite>
       <rules>
         <clear/>
         <rule name="Imported Rule 0" stopProcessing="true">
           <match url="^(img|css|files|js)(.*)$"></match>
           <action type="Rewrite" url="app/webroot/{R:1}{R:2}" appendQueryString="false"></action>
         </rule>
         <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
           <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
           <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
             <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
             <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
           </conditions>
           <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
         </rule>
         <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
           <match url="^$" ignoreCase="false" />
           <action type="Rewrite" url="app/webroot/" />
         </rule>
         <rule name="Imported Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
           <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
           <action type="Rewrite" url="app/webroot/{R:1}" />
         </rule>
         <rule name="Imported Rule 4" stopProcessing="true">
           <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
           <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
             <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
             <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
           </conditions>
           <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
         </rule>
       </rules>
     </rewrite>
   </system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```

Could you anyone please suggest me what i can do for work properly ?